# Android SDK Environment Variables

Tags: android, environment-variables

What are the differences in these Android SDK variables:

- ANDROID_HOME
- ANDROID_SDK_HOME
- ANDROID_AVD_HOME

and what is the page that google explains those variables??

Comment: @cricket_007, I believe google results are tailored based on their geographical location and their personal search. the page that you are referring to as top results appeared for me after filtering results by domain and url. If you have knowledge to help people which I assume you have from 44.5K reputation, start helping people instead of downvoting!

Comment: @AaA Nothing here is downvoted? Besides, *Question shows no research effort* is the exact reason on downvote hover text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the page you are looking for is [Environment Variables](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables.html)

**ANDROID_HOME**

> Is deprecated and you need to use `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` instead. If you continue to use it, the following rules apply:
>       If `ANDROID_HOME` is defined and contains a valid SDK installation, it's value is used instead of the value in `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`.
>       If `ANDROID_HOME` is not defined, the value in `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` is used.
>       If `ANDROID_HOME` is defined but, does not exist or does not contain a valid SDK installation, the value in `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` is used instead.

**ANDROID_SDK_ROOT**

> Sets the path to the SDK installation directory. Once set, the value does not typically change, and can be shared by multiple users on the same machine.

**ANDROID_SDK_HOME**

> By default, the emulator stores configuration files under `$HOME/.android/` (`%username%/.android/` in windows) and AVD data under `$HOME/.android/avd/` (`%username%/.android/avd/` in windows). You can override the defaults by setting the following environment variables. The `emulator -avd <avd_name>` command searches the avd directory in the order of the values in `$ANDROID_AVD_HOME`, `$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android/avd/`, and `$HOME/.android/avd/`.

**ANDROID_AVD_HOME**

> Sets the path to the directory that contains all AVD-specific files, which mostly consist of very large disk images. The default location is `$ANDROID_EMULATOR_HOME/avd/`. You might want to specify a new location if the default location is low on disk space.

*I was looking for the same answer, but soon found out that most people programming for android do not know basic why and how and just follow the instruction given to them by a manager, blog, or manual until they manage to make an APK. at least it is true in my organization*

Comment: thanks bro, I was confused with those vars, but right now I understand the purpose of them :)