# Android SDK tools + Flutter: correct directory structure and environment variables

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

I am having the damnedest time getting [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux) to find the [SDK command-line tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/). I am trying to install the latter by downloading the zip provided at that link and unpacking it in say `${HOME}/Android`. This produces a `tools` directory, and if I run the executable

```
${HOME}/Android/tools/bin/sdkmanager
```

directly (whith any number of options, etc.) I always get an error as documented in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60440509/android-command-line-tools-sdkmanager-always-shows-warning-could-not-create-se). The solution recommended there actually works: move the `tools` directory further down the tree to get the path

```
${HOME}/Android/cmdline-tools/tools/bin/sdkmanager
```

That new intermediate directory **must** be named `cmdline-tools` though; I've tried other things (`Sdk`, `sdk_manager`, etc.) to no effect: the same errors occur.

---

Now, poking around in the cloned [Flutter repo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter), I see in [the file](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/dev/bots/download_android_sdk.sh) `dev/bots/download_android_sdk.sh` that I'm supposed to have the executable

```
$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin/sdkmanager
```

This tips me off that in my setup I need

```
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=${HOME}/Android/cmdline-tools
```

exporting that and running a bunch of `sdkmanager` installation commands (like say

```
$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin/sdkmanager platform-tools
```

and the like) I see that my `${HOME}/Android` directory is starting to get populated with the corresponding directories `platform-tools`, `build-tools`, etc. So those newly-installed directories live at the same level as my `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` which remember, as I'm doing this, is set to `$HOME/Android/cmdline-tools`.

On the other hand though, when I then go look (in the same Flutter repo) in [the file](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/android/android_sdk.dart)

```
packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/android/android_sdk.dart
```

I see that I'm supposed to have the directory `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/build-tools`. This is in direct contradiction with the previous observation that `build-tools` and the like are supposed to be at the same level as `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`, and not *under* it.

My problem is I don't know how to square this apparent self-contradiction in the Flutter codebase. Which is it? In my setup, is `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` supposed to be `$HOME/Android` or `$HOME/Android/cmdline-tools`?

---

**PS**

I [understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863684/android-sdk-environment-variables) that `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` is supposed to be "the SDK installation directory", but in this context this tells me nothing: after all, installing `SDK` is precisely what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a couple comments on GitHub as well, but just be aware that the files in the `dev/` folder in the Flutter repository are mainly intended for CI purposes and for people who are developing the Flutter framework itself.

The scripts you're pointing out are actually stale files that used to help set up some tests we ran on CI. We now set those tests up differently, but forgot to delete the files - so thanks for pointing this out, they're soon to be gone!

The best way to set up your Android SDK is by following the instructions at the Android Studio site. You can either use Studio to do it, or just download the SDK bundle(s) themselves.